# Returning intent result when Activity is closed by back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I start a new `Activity` from the original `Activity` with `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`. I want to return data to the original `Activity` when the user presses the back button, so when returns to the original `Activity`. I tried two methods:

- overriding `onBackPressed()`:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();

      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
      setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  }
  ```
- overriding `onPause()`:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
      setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  }
  ```

Unfortunately, none of them worked (`resultCode` is not `RESULT_OK` in `onActivityResult()`). What's the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since this question is still getting attention, i am posting a more correct answer than the one i accepted two years ago, thanks for [MasterGaurav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/332210/mastergaurav) for the [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121101/returning-intent-result-when-activity-is-closed-by-back-button/30580141#comment43994839_14121142).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: @pratik: Then at the parent activity, will you receive intent onResume() or onNewIntent()?

Comment: @Campiador you should use `onActivityResult` in the parent `Activity`.

Comment: Bad idea.
The problem with original code is -> `setResult` is called after `super.onBackPressed`. Just reverse the order.

Comment: Did not work. I don't know whats going on right now I think its time for me to post another question about resultCode being 0 always.

Comment: @MasterGaurav with my current knowledge of the Android API, i totally agree with you. It is a bad idea to not call `super.onBackPressed`, since that is responsible for important things, like popping the back stack `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, `requestCode` is still not `RESULT_OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new Activity from the original Activity with `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`

when want to return data to the original Activity when the user presses the back button, so when returns to the original Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

if you want to getback result from Newly open Activity just Override

`onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` Method from original Activity

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: Actually i did the exact same thing, as i've written in the OP. This does not work, Pratik's suggestion works though.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While still, people searching for this and OnBackPressed is deprecated. I'm using alternatives that may help someone.

instead onBackPressed method, I'm using this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(FlatMediaActivity.this, callback);
}

OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    @Override
    public void handleOnBackPressed() {
        completeActionAndSetResult();
    }
};
```

and here is the completeActionAndSetResult()

```
private void completeActionAndSetResult() {
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putIntegerArrayListExtra(SELECTION_LIST, selected);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        callback.remove(); //remove callback
        finish();
    }
```