# Can onBackPressed set and return an intent result?

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

My MainActivity can call two different activities (a & b).  Activity A is called as follows:

```
   private View.OnLongClickListener alc = new View.OnLongClickListener(){
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(j, 1);
        return true;
    }
};
```

The A activity has two buttons, one to SAVE and one to CANCEL.  The SAVE returns a result...

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSave:
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btnCxl:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
```

This works PERFECTLY!!

I want the similar return for Activity B.  I modified it's Intent call as follows...

```
private View.OnClickListener ac = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(j, 1);
    }
};
```

In the B activity, I don't have a SAVE button to "catch".   After browsing, I see the `onBackPressed()` is available because that is how I am leaving this activity usually.   I read I should be able to put the result code in there elsewhere online..

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    }
```

Putting in some `Log.i` calls in my `onActivityResult`in the MainActivity...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("MYLOG","In Result");
    if (requestCode==1) {
        Log.i("MYLOG","In Result 1");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("MYLOG","In Result 1 OK");
            // Do some data processing and display here!!
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned, A activity, works fine... hits all three `Log.i` statements.    B activity hits first two, but never hits 3rd.

What am I missing here?

Thanks Pete

Comment: have u tried my answer @peter?

Comment: while OnBackPressed is deprecated, You can find an alternative here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77422459/14163435

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add finish in `onbackpress`

```
     super.onBackPressed();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: yes, I tried that too.   I put the `finish()` at the end and had the same result.   I took it out before posting this to see if that had an effect.   No change.

Comment: you should put super.onBackPressed() after setResult()  and remove finish()

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is work:

- MyActivity override onOptionsItemSelected void, do not use finish(); in home case,
  code bellow instead :

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId())
  {
  case android.R.id.home:
  onBackPressed();
  return true;
  default:break;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

Then, you much override onBackPressed:

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();//
    Intent intent_return = getIntent();
    intent_return.putExtra("idPaid",p.getId());
    intent_return.putExtra("position", rootPosition);
    intent_return.putExtra("isEdit", isEdit);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent_return);
    finish();
}
```

Now, intent data will be return in onActivityResult in YourFragment.
Hope it help for you !