# How to send data by click back button?

Tags: android, android-intent, onbackpressed

I'm using two activities, MainActivity & SubActivity.

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        ...
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sub = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
                sub.putExtra("name", "a");
                startActivity(sub);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> SubActivity

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        ...
        text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In this case, if I change the text in `EditText` in SubActivity, I want to send changed text data to MainActivity when back button pressed in SubActivity(It means SubActivity `onDestroy()`). I don't want to make the second MainActivity like this in SubActivity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", text.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Is there any way to send text data when SubActivity removed from the activity stack?

Comment: You can use sharedPref to save data. and use this in Main activity

Comment: have a look to this  nice doc from google that explain everything in deep https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: in case someone facing a problem with onBackPressed being deprecated, Please see my alternative answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77422459/14163435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      Button button;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate() {
      ...
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent sub = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
              sub.putExtra("name", "a");
              startActivityForResult(sub , 2);
        }
    }
}
@Override  
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
   {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  
                        String message=data.getStringExtra("name");   
                        textView1.setText(message);  
                     }  
   }  
}
```

And

```
      @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", text.getText().toString());
        setResult(2,intent);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) if you expect to have a return from the started activity.

After that, you'll also need to implement `onActivityResult()` method on the start activity to actually read the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult instead of startActivity

**MainActivity :**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    String name= "a";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        ...
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sub = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
                sub.putExtra("name", name);
                startActivityForResult(sub,100);
            }
        }
    }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 100) {
              String name = data.getStringExtra("name);
                text.setText(name);
            } 
         }
      }
}
```

**SubActivity:**

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
        ...
        text.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
       resultIntent.putExtra("name", "your_editext_value");
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
       finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreference` for storing value and update it or use it anywhere instead of using `Intent`

like In `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    ...

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  Editor edit=sp.edit();
  edit.putString("name","a");
  edit.commit();
            Intent sub = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);

            startActivity(sub);
        }
    }
} }
```

and In `SubActivity`

```
public class SubActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText text;
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    ...
    text.setText(sp.getString("name",""));
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  Editor edit=sp.edit();
 edit.putString("name",s.toString);
  edit.commit();
} });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   super.onBackPressed();
}}
```

To use value from `SharedPreference`

```
sp.getString("name","");
```

For using `SharedPreference` look at this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java